# JFreeChart, Java itext Graph Size

Tags: java, swing, itext, jfreechart

I am trying to generate a **PDF** with **JFreeChart graph** using Java iText API 2.1. When Graph is displyed in JFrame, it has 20 (x-axis) points, once I pass graph to PDF it turns down x-axis (8-10) points.

Still the graph is right, but I want the graph in the same way as it displayed in JFrame.

In my code, If I increase the size, the graph goes out of the page.

```
try {
        document.newPage();
        float width = 500;
        float height = 330;
        PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
        PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(width, height);
        Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(width, height, new DefaultFontMapper());
        Rectangle2D rectangle2d = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, width, height);
        graphs.g1().draw(graphics2d, rectangle2d);
        graphics2d.dispose();
        Image chartImage = Image.getInstance(template);
        document.add(chartImage);
        //contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, height);
    } catch (BadElementException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SavePDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SavePDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this question because, there is no other possible way to do it.

Because of the width (500) and height (330), the graph is auto adjusted to fit the Dimension. So its not possible to show all the points at this dimensions.